# Google Chrome or Chromium for Docker CentOS7 amazonlinux2 on arm64 / aarch64

Tags: docker, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver, chromium, arm64

***I always prefer to explain how I got here, so if you only care for the question, skip to the end!***

**The background story for those who are curious:**

I'm having a docker environment using `amazonlinux:2` in which I use chromedriver to run some tests.

It all worked until I switched to a MacBook with M1 chip. Neither with a cross compiled docker container, nor with an arm64 compiled docker container, I was able to run the following test script:

```py
import time

from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')
options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
options.add_argument('--fullscreen')
options.add_argument('--remote-debugging-port=9222')
options.binary_location = '/usr/local/bin/chromedriver'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, service_args=["--verbose", "--log-path=/opt/chromedriver.log"])

driver.get('http://www.google.com/')

time.sleep(5) # Let the user actually see something!

search_box = driver.find_element_by_name('q')

search_box.send_keys('ChromeDriver')

search_box.submit()

time.sleep(5) # Let the user actually see something!

driver.quit()
```

When I compile the container with `--platform=linux/amd64`, the script crashes because apparently there's a problem with running Chrome in a cross compiled container with chromedriver. It just always crashes.

When I compile the `amazonlinux:2` image without the `--platform` parameter, I have the problem that there's no chrome available for centos7 on arm64 architecture.

**And that's where I am now**

I'm trying to compile chromium by myself to add to the image and use instead. I tried to follow the [Linux Chromium Arm Recipes](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/HEAD/docs/linux/chromium_arm.md) which brings me to the [Chromium Build Instructions](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/main/docs/linux/build_instructions.md#Get-the-code).

But I'm already at the end when I run

```
$ fetch --nohooks chromium
```

which crashes with the error:

```
bootstrap-2@3.8.10.chromium.23_bin/python3/bin/python3: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.27' not found (required by bootstrap-2@3.8.10.chromium.23_bin/python3/bin/python3)
cat: /opt/depot_tools/python3_bin_reldir.txt: No such file or directory
[E2022-06-15T15:13:00.163840Z 717 0 annotate.go:273] goroutine 1:
#0 go.chromium.org/luci/vpython/venv/config.go:309 - venv.(*Config).resolvePythonInterpreter()
  reason: none of [/opt/depot_tools//python3] matched specification 3.8.0

#1 go.chromium.org/luci/vpython/venv/config.go:153 - venv.(*Config).resolveRuntime()
  reason: failed to resolve system Python interpreter

#2 go.chromium.org/luci/vpython/venv/venv.go:143 - venv.With()
  reason: failed to resolve python runtime

#3 go.chromium.org/luci/vpython/run.go:60 - vpython.Run()
#4 go.chromium.org/luci/vpython/application/application.go:327 - application.(*application).mainImpl()
#5 go.chromium.org/luci/vpython/application/application.go:416 - application.(*Config).Main.func1()
#6 go.chromium.org/luci/vpython/application/support.go:46 - application.run()
#7 go.chromium.org/luci/vpython/application/application.go:415 - application.(*Config).Main()
#8 vpython/main.go:112 - main.mainImpl()
#9 vpython/main.go:118 - main.main()
#10 runtime/proc.go:225 - runtime.main()
#11 runtime/asm_arm64.s:1130 - runtime.goexit()
```

which again looks like a dead end as I would prefer not having to replace a core lib.

**So after several tries to get it up and running by myself, I'm asking for your help:**

How can I get chromedriver with chrome or chromium up and running on the `amazonlinux:2` docker image (which uses CentOS7) and `arm64`/`aarch64` architecture?

Comment: Where you lucky to resolve the issue? I'm still having troubles building arm64 lambdas with Chromium package inside, still no binaries available.

Comment: I wasn't. The problem is still the same. The solution would be to wait for the successor of amazonlinux2 to be official and use this instead.